# Test web by crawling all pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, web-crawler

I develop web site in ASP.NET MVC 3 and since Views are compiled after first visit it sometimes happens to me, that I release web site with some Vies with errors (like typos).

I'd like to create something like unit test which will try to visit all pages, to avoid any errors in views.

It should be quite easy to create another program which will crawl web on the localhost but I'd like to integrate it to unit test loop. Is this possible?

Should I write write simple crawler myself or should I use something existing?

Also It would be nice to get list of pages and their number of connections to see which pages are accessible by how many links. The crawler should crawl only my web, not external links. Also It can help to find pages which are not accesible from starting point (index page).

My web has like 100 pages so performance is not the problem :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: here's an [article](http://yassershaikh.com/introduction-to-web-scraping-with-httpwebrequest-using-asp-net-mvc3/) incase u want to write a simple crawler

Answer (score 3):

Try **"Search Engine Optimization Toolkit"** very good tool:

**Use Site Analysis module**

[Search Engine Optimization Toolkit](http://www.iis.net/download/seotoolkit)

**Site Analysis Features**

Fully featured crawler engine

Configurable number of concurrent requests to allow users to crawl their Web site without incurring additional processing. This can be configured from 1 to 16 concurrent requests.

Support for Robots.txt, allowing you to customize the locations where the crawler should analyze and which locations should be ignored.

Support for Sitemap files allowing you to specify additional locations to be analyzed.

Support for overriding ‘noindex’ and ‘nofollow’ metatags to allow you to analyze pages to help improve customer experience even when search engines will not process them.

Configurable limits for analysis, maximum number of URLs to download, and maximum number of kilobytes to download per URL.

Configurable options for including content from only your directories or the entire site and sub domains.

View detailed summary of Web site analysis results through a rich dashboard

Feature rich Query Builder interface that allows you to build custom reports

Quick access to common tasks

Display of detailed information for each URL

View detailed route analysis showing unique routes to better understand the way search engines reach your content

**"Linkbot"** is another tool you can look that can be helpful:

Linkbot is an award winning suite of Web site management utilities that helps webmasters track down and repair problems on their sites. Linkbot contains all the tools needed to maintain an error-free site in one integrated package: high performance multitasking engine for rapid site analysis, find and repair broken links, locate slow and outdated pages, find orphaned files that are no longer being used, map out the structure and organization of the site, check password protected and secure areas, comprehensive HTML reporting, automatically generate a what's new page, create gallery of all the images on your site and much more!

Comment: This is very nice and strong tool and it can solve my problems. I will definitely check it out but I rather seek for some simpler solution, that can be integrated to unit tests framework just to check whether all pages are generated without any errors.

Comment: don't know why @KapilKhandelwal did not put any link for linkbot but the description of it sounds like an ads..

Answer (score 1):

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/09/compiling-mvc-views-in-a-build-environment.aspx

Just follow this, and views will be built in either debug or release. When there are view compiler errors, the build will fail.

On the other hand if you still want to crawl in order to look for broken links, check out [WebDriver](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver).

Comment: Yeah, I know about building views but it changes my compile time from 6 sec to 26 sec (which is pain). And I want to check them in only when I am releasing (running unit tests) because sometimes I just compile project to be able to keep updating views (compiling all views will throw me errors which I'm aware of). I will check the WebDriver though.

Comment: Yeah, compiling views can take a while. You could also invest in ReSharper, which will warn out about errors or broken links in view files, but R# is not free unless your project is OSS. WebDriver can be used in any CLR unit test framework. An alternative is WatiN, but last I checked, it could not drive Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

NightElfik,

the simplest way to catch typos is to compile the solution in `Release` mode (rather than the default `Debug` mode), that way, all views are compiled and errors are shown in the `Error List`. Of course, you you need to go beyond this (such as finding inaccesible links), but that would certainly catch all your typos.

Comment: No, I always compile the solution in release mode for releasing and Views are not compiled (I am talking about Views in Razor). Just tried. Also sometimes I copy just new views to the release web if no DLLs are changed. I think there is option to pre-compile all views on build bu it is not recommended.